# Passing the ID of the gridview's selected record to another page using querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, query-string

I have a gridview with selection enabled, I also added a button under it that is supposed to take the user to another page with a formview waiting to display the selected record's complete information. How do i pass the ID as a query string and use it in the sqldatasource in the other page?

My gridview has

```
ID
Name
```

The formview will show

```
ID
Name
Description
Uploader
Audience
Category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the value from the selected row and redirect on post back.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx

```
  Sub CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow
    Response.redirect(String.Format("detailsPage.aspx?id={0}", row.cells(x).text))
  End Sub

  void CustomersGridView_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     GridViewRow row = CustomersGridView.SelectedRow;
     Response.Redirect(String.Format("detailsPage.aspx?id={0}", row.cells[x].text));

  }
```

Where x is the cell that holds the ID

On the details page assuming a stored procedure:

```
Dim aSource As New SqlDataSource
 aSource.ConnectionString = {your connection string})
 aSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
 aSource.SelectCommand = {Your stored procedure name}
 aSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure
 aSource.SelectParameters.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter("ID", Data.DbType.String, Request.QueryString(0)))

 SqlDataSource aSource;
 aSource.ConnectionString = {your connection string});
 aSource.ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient";
 aSource.SelectCommand = {Your stored procedure name};
 aSource.SelectCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
 aSource.SelectParameters.Add(New System.Web.UI.WebControls.Parameter("ID", Data.DbType.String, Request.QueryString[0]));
```

EDIT: From seeing your response to another answer:

I am fairly certain that the selected row should be visible to your submit function as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, i forgot to add the C# tag, i just did. Thank you though.

Comment: the method is the same, the syntax is just a bit different.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Next time, when asking, add as much information as possible. I took some assumptions when answering, thought that some times leads to an acceptable answer, it still makes it much harder to help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<asp:HyperLinkField>`.

Eg.:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
   <Columns>
     <asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="ID" 
         DataNavigateUrlFormatString="/detailsPage.aspx?id={0}"
        DataTextField="ID" HeaderText="ID" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Refer:

[HyperLinkField Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield%28v=vs.100%29.aspx): Represents a field that is displayed as a hyperlink in a data-bound control.

Comment: This is a nice easy way to do this.

Comment: thanks for the response, but i want to add the code in the button, because im not displaying the survey's ID to the user.

Comment: @BasharKH But you have said in your question that you want to use querystring to pass the value betweeen pages.